# MapR-FS: What are the limitations on open source edition

Tags: open-source

I'm looking to use [MapR-FS](https://mapr.com/products/mapr-fs/) and trying to understand the [differences between the open-source and enterprise editions](https://mapr.com/products/mapr-distribution-editions/).

The features that I want to use ("Direct Access NFS" and "MapR POSIX Client") have limitations with little details.

So, the practical question is: **Is it possible to use open-source Mapr-fs in a distributed manner and achieve minimal high-availability and fault-tolerance?**

Comment: From a quick look at their web site, it seems that describing MapR-FS as "open source" is entirely contrary to the facts.  They say they have a "community edition" but what they mean by that is a time-limited, feature-crippled subset of their "enterprise edition".  i.e. proprietary shareware.  They don't mean open source or free software or anything similar to that.   There are numerous open source HA systems available if an open source license is one of your selection criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapR is a great distributive file system which comes in two models: community edition and enterprise edition. The community edition lacks some features like High Availability and Global Table Replication for MapR-DB. You can get the overview and full comparison [here](https://mapr.com/products/mapr-distribution-editions/).

Comment: Thanks, @varnit. I have listed this link in my question because this page only informs superficial details about the differences. Does the community version achieve minimal high-availability and fault-tolerance or not?

Comment: their model is very confusing i must admit and after i have gone through their website i don't think so that they provide high availability on community edition and there is no benefit of deploying anything in production without high availability

Comment: why don't you give mapR a try on aws https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B010GJS5WO

Answer (score 0):

[You can find here page license extraction](https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/AdvancedInstallation/c_installer_faq.html)
[image]

Comment: Pictures of text are less than ideal; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors